# Why doesn't line-height work on FF/3.5.8(Mac)?

Tags: css, firefox

I can't get line-height on a **text input** to work on **Firefox 3.5.8/(Mac)**. Works flawlessly on:

- IE6
- IE7
- IE8
- FF3.6/PC
- FF3.6/Mac
- Safari

Test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>asd</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.0r4/build/reset/reset-min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="Hello" style="line-height:50px;height:50px;font-size:16px;" />
<input type="text" value="Hello" style="padding:17px 0;font-size:16px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Is there an alternate solution or any idea how to fix this?

---

**Edit:** Updated the test code, to compare line-height vs. padding technique. Padding works on all above browsers **except IE8**. Whaat?

I can't test on FF/3.5.8 anymore, could someone please report the result from this browser on any plattform?

I'm now thinking this is a Firefox 3.5.8 issue, plattform independent.

Comment: Working on example code, sorry I posted too early..

Comment: Updated the question. Noticed this was only affected by Firefox 3.5.8/Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds suspiciously similar to [bug 349259](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349259). The reason back then was that Mozilla was intentionally enforcing a `line-height: normal` rule for text inputs via an `!important` directive, and the bug is still open. Verifying with the [current source code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/063f18ccd02f/layout/style/forms.css#l99) for the Firefox trunk shows that this should still be in effect, so I don't really understand how it could work in Firefox 3.6...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware this doesn't work on the Mac. Googling shows people talking of problems with it being too big/too small or not working as expected, and they even talk of using it in earlier versions, but no one has said it doesn't work at all. So I question your assumption that it doesn't work at all.

EDIT: I got FF and Safari switched around due to the Mac reference.

Comment: Sadly, my assumptions are based on actual results :-(

Comment: Seems Webkit sets input to 'inline-block' but Firefox sets line-height to 'normal' and '!important' so that's why it can't be changed.

Comment: Wait, if that's just the browser stylesheet, sure it can be changed, you just have to override it by getting specific on the selectors, right? Like #content input.dammit { line-height:200% !important; }

Comment: @DN User stylesheets override author stylesheets and this !important rule is in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is still affecting FF 3.6. Its a real pain in the you know what too.

The mean little piece of code lives on line 99 of forms.css for FF

line-height:normal !important;

I seem to be able to override it for 3.5.8, but for some reason 3.6 ignores my override with my own !important.

Comment: I take that back. I can't override it in either. Guess you can't override browser stylesheets. Bastards!

Comment: Doesn't http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules say it should be overrideable? I think it's weird, we as a community should do something :p